# PHP/MySQL Search results. Auto redirect if only one result

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple SQL Queries with While loops in PHP for a search form.

There are 3 blocks of code in total, each selected from a different table and before the while loop i use

```
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    ...show results here
}
```

I would like to have it so if there is only one result returned for the 3 blocks of code, it will automatically redirect to a different page.

For example, i am searching for Customers, Contacts and Invoices. So they are the 3 different blocks of code / queries i have.

If i search for Company A and there is 1 record returned in the customers query and 0 records returned in Contacts and Invoices, it should redirect to the customer page. However if there is 2 records returned it should just display the search results.

and the same for Customers, Contacts and Invoices

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into? Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: `if(condition){ do something } else{ do something else }` *right Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Right Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to a new page, use `header()`:

```
header("Location: /url/to/company/page?id=$companyId");
```

Your conditional needs to handle at least three situations: No results, a single result, and multiple results:

```
switch (mysql_num_rows($rs)) {
    case 0:
        $this->noResultsFound();
        break;
    case 1:
        header("Location: /url/to/company/page?id=" . $rs[0]['companyId']);
        break;
    default:
        $this->showResults($rs);
        break;
 }
```

As stated in the comments, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated; they have been replaced by better, safer alternatives. Consider investigating the benefits of [PDO](http://php.net/manual/book.pdo.php).

It is generally bad practice to use `die()` statements in production code. However, one of the rare exceptions is in conjunction with the use of `header()`. It may not be obvious, but when you redirect with `header()`, the rest of your script continues to run before the HTTP header with the redirect instruction is sent to the browser. In the case of poorly-structured code, this can lead to unexpected results.

To avoid that problem, insert a `die()` statement immediately after the `header()` line.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the following suffice?

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    header("Location: other_script.php");
} elseif (mysql_num_rows($result) > 1) {
    // ... show results ...
} else {
    // ... no results ...
}
```

In case I understood your question wrong and you have multiple queries but want to know the total results, thats as simple as:

```
$one = mysql_num_rows($result_one);
$two = mysql_num_rows($result_two);
$three = mysql_num_rows($result_three);
$total = $one + $two + $three;
if ($total == 1) {
    header("Location: other_page.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely simplified code, and can be highly optimized, but I think this is what you're looking for.

```
//After queries you've got 3 arrays:
$customers = [...];
$contacts = [...];
$invoices = [...];

//Determine if there's only 1 result of 1 category returned from the queries:
if(sizeof($customers)==1 && sizeof($contacts)==0 && sizeof($invoices)==0){
// Redirect to customers...
} elseif(sizeof($customers)==0 && sizeof($contacts)==1 && sizeof($invoices)==0) {
// Redirect to contacts...
} elseif(sizeof($customers)==0 && sizeof($contacts)==0 && sizeof($invoices)==1){
// Redirect to invoices...
} else {
// Redirect to results page...
}
```